# C# WinForms - Exclude edge from this.Bounds

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I'm using this code to grab an image of my form:

```
        Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
        bitmapScreen = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        using (Graphics gImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapScreen))
        {
            gImage.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }
```

However, in Windows 10, I'm getting the desktop or other windows showing through as the bounds are wide due to the transparent/shaded edges outside of my actual content.  How can I limit this bitmap to the actual window/form bounds?

It seems as though these extra edges occur on the left, bottom and right only.  (See picture)[Extra Edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLGH0.png)

Comment: The client rectangle is the interior area of your window, which properly excludes the edges.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
        bitmapScreen = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        this.DrawToBitmap(bitmapScreen, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmapScreen.Size));
```